# С января 2022 года зарубежные компании с >500К посетителей в сутки должны открыть в России филиал

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, stackexchange

1 января 2022 года вступит в силу законопроект № 1176731-7 «[О деятельности иностранных лиц в информационно-телекоммуникационной сети "Интернет" на территории Российской Федерации](https://sozd.duma.gov.ru/bill/1176731-7)». **Уже есть [текст проекта в третьем чтении](https://sozd.duma.gov.ru/download/05B6BBA2-79EE-46C6-9CAF-A7A252B532B5), doc-файл, 38 страниц**.

**Если на всём StackExchange больше пятисот тысяч пользователей из России в день**, этот закон будет актуален для Николаса как для пока что единственного российского сотрудника, которому придётся всё объяснять и организовывать наверху, и StackOverflow, Inc. как непосредственно компании. Ну и, скорее всего, потребуются свободные руки и головы из русскоязычных сообществ (ru.stackoverflow.com, russian.stackexchange.com, rus.stackexchange.com).

### Почему StackOverflow, Inc. попадёт под закон

> Под иностранным лицом, осуществляющим деятельность в сети «Интернет» на территории Российской Федерации, понимается иностранное лицо, [...] является владельцем сайта [...] доступ к которым в течение суток составляет более пятисот тысяч пользователей сети «Интернет», находящихся на территории Российской Федерации [...], а также при одном из следующих условий:
>
> 1. на информационном ресурсе иностранного лица предоставляется и (или) распространяется информация на государственном языке Российской Федерации [...];
> 2. [...]
> 3. иностранное лицо осуществляет обработку сведений о пользователях, находящихся на территории Российской Федерации.
>
> Иностранным лицом [...] признается также:
>
> 1. [...]
> 2. иностранное лицо, осуществляющее деятельность [...] программ [...] которые предназначены и (или) используются для приема, передачи, доставки и (или) обработки электронных сообщений пользователей сети «Интернет», в том числе находящихся на территории Российской Федерации [...].

### Что компания обязана из-за этого делать

> Иностранное лицо, осуществляющее деятельность в сети «Интернет» на территории Российской Федерации, обязано:
>
> 1. разместить на информационном ресурсе электронную форму для направления обращений российских граждан и организаций, требования к которой устанавливаются федеральным органом исполнительной власти, осуществляющим функции по контролю и надзору в сфере средств массовой информации, массовых коммуникаций, информационных технологий и связи;
> 2. зарегистрировать личный кабинет на официальном сайте федерального органа исполнительной власти, осуществляющего функции по контролю и надзору [...] и использовать его для взаимодействия с государственными органами Российской Федерации;
> 3. создать филиал, или открыть представительство, или учредить российское юридическое лицо и обеспечить функционирование на территории Российской Федерации филиала, или представительства, или российского юридического лица в соответствии с требованиями, предусмотренными статьей 7 настоящего Федерального закона.

В самом тексте законопроекта расписано, кто, что, как, когда и при каких условиях. Язык там перегруженный, но в целом всё чётко и ясно.

Comment: Интересно, а что сделает РФ, если иностранная компания просто проигнорирует все эти требования? Может, это государству надо задуматься - чего это оно недодает своим гражданам настолько, что полмиллиона их идет на импортный ресурс? :) Заблокирует и лишит эти 500К пользователей возможности получения нужного им - тем самым, понятно, резко повысив рейтинг власти в глазах полумиллиона своих граждан? :)

Comment: Очередной никому не нужный, кроме властей закон. Видно же, что делается для того, чтобы целенаправленно отключить половину ресурсов, с целью замедления распространения важной, в том числе и компрометирующей властей информации.

Comment: Больше это касается крупнейших социальных сетей. Как мне кажется, SO (ruSO) не тот ресурс, на который обратят внимание. Уверен, Николай может спать спокойно. Да и мы с вами. Не нужно лишней паники. Продолжаем работать :)

Comment: @Harry, как раз для тех кому это интересно, в вопрос добавлена ссылка (та что жирным шрифтом) на текст закона.

Comment: @yar85 "Идиотизм наших законов компенсируется их невыполнением" :) Вы всерьез думаете, что я буду это все читать? :)

Comment: @Sevastopol' а как же ситуация с linkedin? Его конечно по другому закону блокировали, но всё-таки заблокировали. Тут скорее чисто лотерея.

Comment: @Harry, я всерьез думаю, что этот вопрос-обсуждение не о власти в РФ. И еще, что Мета предназначена не для кухонно-политических постов, а для обсуждения ruSO (вопрос - онтопик, т.к. имеет отношение к stackoverflow на русском; рассуждения о власти - оффтопик, так как не в тему сайта)

Comment: @yar85 Как говорится, "это вы, доктор, такие картинки показываете" - какой пост, такие и комментарии он вызывает. Почему-то к посту у вас претензий нет, несмотря на его явную политизированность :)

Comment: К вопросу претензий нет потому что он предполагает обсуждение **перспектив ruSO** в контексте принятого закона. Оправданиями чисто политических комментариев вне контекста SO я не интересовался, т.к. они не могут повлиять на точку зрения "чистая политота без прямого отношения к stackoverflow == оффтоп". Если же помимо оправданий есть _аргументы_ опровергающие эту точку зрения, то попрошу к этим аргументам сразу и перейти (так будет конструктивнее).

Comment: Ну а чо, если @NicolasChabanovsky не будет справляться с обязанностями по ФЗ - я согласен буду ему помочь :)

Comment: @Barmaley я может глупость спрошу - но а сервер ruSO в России ?

Comment: @MaximLensky без понятия

Comment: @Barmaley тогда если сервер so/ruSO находится где то не в раше этот закон не сработает

Comment: @MaximLensky вы это о чем? И к чему эта дискуссия? Даже если сервера не в России - что это меняет? Заблокируют на хрен этот SO и делов то - конечно часть народа пересядет на VPN, но траффик упадет на порядок или даже 2. LinkedIn - убили в России и небо не обрушилось. VK/Яндекс заблочили на Украине и тоже как то живут. Сейчас просто время такое - идет сегментация некогда единого тырнета.

Comment: @Barmaley понял ..спс за разъяснения

Answer (score 17):

В [статистике](//stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-questions) указано, что у нас только 75K посещений в день, что довольно далеко от 500K. Причём, подозреваю, что число посещений не предполагает, что посещения сделаны уникальными пользователями.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Хм, а на enSO сколько пользователей из России? Если всего там 11 миллионов, вполне себе может быть 500 тысяч из России

Comment: Хотя, доля населения России к миру всего 1,85%, так что, наверное, и тут примерно такую пропорцию следует ожидать, а это всего 200 тысяч

Comment: Ну значит, пока можно ничего не делать. Возможно, потом когда все привыкнут, границу начнут постепенно понижать, чтобы уловить в сеть и поменьше рыбёшку.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, enSO не подпадает из-за того, что они русский не используют. Но вообще там 11M в день.